# Deer in Headlights Punchline

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

When somebody is caught by the element of surprise she or he looks strange Sometimes like a Deer in Headlights.

- Is there a way to say that in german in a way that flows verbaly aka not using a massive descriptive sencence-costruction while you crash and burn burning brain cells and after having lost the quick time window to throw the punchline? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a very similar expression, but [over here we have mostly "Rehe" (roe deer) crossing the road](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32921/deer-in-german-hirsch-reh/32923#32923). So the German version is

> wie ein Reh im Scheinwerferlicht

Comment: Den Ausdruck habe ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: @KritikerderElche Als Norddeutscher ist mir der Ausdruck gut bekannt.

Comment: Auch wenn ich die meisten Jahre meines Lebens, insbesondere auch Kindheit und Jugend, im Norden verbracht habe und verbringe, ist das für mich kein geläufiger Ausdruck

Comment: Some arbitrarily chosen examples: "Wie ein Reh im Scheinwerferlicht" ([WiWo 2016](https://www.wiwo.de/unternehmen/it/start-up-szene-in-london-wie-ein-reh-im-scheinwerferlicht/14949982.html), about start-ups in London confronted by the looming brexit). "Wie ein Reh im Scheinwerferlicht" ([taz 2018](https://taz.de/Oeffentlich-Rechtliche-und-der-Rechtsruck/!5541020/), about far-right attacks on German public media). "Die schaut immer drein wie ein Reh im Scheinwerferlicht" ([forum posting 2021](https://www.fernsehserien.de/solo-fuer-weiss/community) about an actress in a crime serial).

Comment: Das Internet sagt: *fränkische Redewendung „Du schaust wie a Achala wenns blitzt“*

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Da kenne ich die Version, "Du schaust wie die Kuh, wenn's donnert!" Aber das ist merklich abwertender als "wie ein Reh im Scheinwerferlicht".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Ich halte in diesem Fall das Vorhandensein von ein paar Beispielen für sich genommen nicht für aussagekräftig. Der Verweis auf das Reh im Scheinwerferlicht ist keineswegs besonders "blumig" oder originell. Wenn man den Spruch hört (und ich hatte ihn noch nie gehört), weiß man sofort, was gemeint ist, und der Vergleich ist bei dem zugehörigen Gesichtsausdruck auch relativ naheliegend. Es muss sich also nicht um eine feste Redewendung handeln, nur damit im Lauf der Zeit verschiedene Sprecher auf diesen Vergleich gekommen sind.

Comment: @infinitezero Can you say whether it has been in use for a long time? See Jörg W Mittag's answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost The question wasn't adressed at me, but I remember being familiar with the German expression long before I first heard the English equivalent. And the latter was many years ago, as well. So from my experience it's clearly not a handful of recent translations.

Answer (score 7):

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verdattert) offers an adjektive (apparently in use since 18th century, so it could be considered as dated), which is marked as colloquial:

> verdattert

and explains:

> durch eine unerwartete Situation überrascht, verwirrt

(confused by unexpected situation).

It is somewhat more generic, since it is not restricted to some kind of facial distortion, but could also cover other reactions as stuttering. Note that the verb corresponding to this participle is even more unusual.

Answer (score 6):

> When somebody is caught by the element of surprise she or he looks strange Sometimes like a Deer in Headlights.

That is *not* what that idiom means. It means *to be unable to move, think, or act due to being surprised by a frightening situation*, frozen in fear.

The idiomatic translation of that would be *wie das Kaninchen vor der Schlange* (*like the rabbit before the snake*).

I have never heard the expression in [Henning Kockerbeck's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/67931/11180) before, and the fact that all his findings are from 2016 or later seems to indicate that it is a *false friend* or a literal translation by someone who reads or hears a lot of English instead of an idiomatic translation.

An example of a wrong literal translation would be to translate *to kill two birds with one stone* as *zwei Vögel mit einem Stein(wurf) töten*. The correct, idiomatic translation is *zwei Fliegen mit einer Klappe schlagen* (*swat two flies with one swatter*).

I suspect that the examples found by Henning Kockerbeck are actually similar non-idiomatic literal translations. This suspicion is reinforced by the fact that the oldest example he found is from 2016, which is well into the age of ubiquitous access to YouTube, Netflix, and more generally the (predominantly English) World Wide Web.

I have some personal experience with this because it actually happens to me sometimes. Due to my job and my preference for reading books and watching movies and TV in English, I speak, hear, write, and read so much English that I sometimes accidentally translate idiomatic English phrases literally, because the English idioms are more present in my head than the corresponding German ones. For example, I can never figure out how to say *edge case* in German, and have accidentally said *Eckenfall* at least once. (Correct would be *Randbedingung*.)

Comment: Genau, das fasst auch meine Geanken gut zusammen. Das Kaninchen vor der Schlange würde hier in der tat gut passen - und das habe ich auch schon vor Jahrzehnten gehört (aber tatsächlicn auch nicht so präsent, dass ich es aktiv verwende).

Comment: edge case != Randbedingung. edge case = Spezialfall. Randbedingung = bounding condition. At least in the way science uses it.

Comment: @planetmaker: That's interesting. I always thought special case = Spezialfall. So, if edge case = Spezialfall, then what is special case?

Comment: 'special case' and 'edge case' sind meines Wissen nach synonym. Wobei 'edge case' das deutlich gebräuchlichere Wort ist. Auch wenn ein Muttersprachler vielleicht Unterschiede ausmachen kann, eventuell in dem Sinne, das 'edge case' ein lästiger Spezialfall ist, der nicht in das generelle Schema passt, 'special case' hingegen nur ungewöhnlich. Jedoch ist 'edge case' ist in keinem Fall eine Randbedingung. Etwas weniger gebräuchlich könnte man es ggf. noch mit 'Grenzfall' übersetzen.

Comment: “Es regnet Katzen und Hunde”. (Supposedly an idiom in English, but I can’t remember ever actually hearing it).

Comment: "It's raining cats and dogs" -> "Es regnet junge Hunde"

Comment: I agree to you that it sounds like a literal translation. There are other examples like https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/64855/niedrig-h%c3%a4ngende-fr%c3%bcchte. BUT: infinitezero comments "Als Norddeutscher ist mir der Ausdruck gut bekannt". So perhaps there is some "regional use".